# Javascript Console jquery slideDown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, submenu

Javscript code

/* ---------- Submenu  ---------- */

```
$('.dropmenu').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown();

});
```

webpage code

```
    <li>
        <a class="dropmenu" href=""><i class="fa-icon-folder-close-alt"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Databases</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="/rinks"><i class="fa-icon-file-alt"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Rinks</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href=""><i class="fa-icon-file-alt"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Users</span></a></li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
```

So I have this piece of code that triggers a dropdown menu to expand when the element 
"a class="dropmenu" href=" is clicked.

I am trying to trigger this event when another element has a value set to it but I can't figure out how to call the slidedown function from the console.

I dont want to trigger with the click() command. I want to be able to execute $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown(); but from the console side. That way I can call other functions like slideToggle. Basically I want to be able to rung the below code to trigger the slidedown, not the click event, I would remove the click event.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   //Message functions
    if (document.getElementbyId("testing").value == "BestGame"){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown();

    }
```

Comment: `$('.dropmenu').trigger('click')`

Comment: `$('.dropmenu').click();`

Comment: The above two are synonymous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a method to be called in the click event

```
 $('.dropmenu').click(function (e) {
     var el = this;
     e.preventDefault();
     toggleMenu(el);
 };
 var toggleMenu = function (el) {
     $(el).parent().find('ul').slideDown();
 }
```

So from the console all you would have to do is

```
 toggleMenu('.dropmenu')
```